# Try/catch in PowerShell when installing Chocolatey packages

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to create a script for installing Chocolatey packages in PowerShell. This works fine, but I want to parse the output from Chocolatey. What I'm thinking about is something like

```
$package = "something I want"
try         
{
    $installCommand = "choco install $package"
    iex $installCommand -ErrorAction Stop -WarningAction Stop
}
catch
{
    #Print error messages, i.e. $_.Exception.Message
}
```

I'm pretty new to PowerShell, and I've tried to figure out how to use try/catch. I've tried

```
try {
    $command = "choco install asdasdasdasdasdad"
    iex $command -ErrorAction Stop -WarningAction Stop
}
catch  {
    $message = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host $message
}
```

But this gives me

```
Installing the following packages: asdasdasdasdasdad
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
asdasdasdasdasdad not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed. 
If you specified a particular version and are receiving this message, it is possible that the package name exists but the version does not.
Version: ""  Source(s): "https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/"

Chocolatey installed 0/1 package(s). 1 package(s) failed. 
See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
Failures:
  - asdasdasdasdasdad
```

Any tips? In advance, thank you!

---

I found a code sample that helps me on my way:

```
function testInstall
{
    Param (
        [string] $package
    )

    Begin
    {
        Write-Host "Now in Begin.. Going on!"
    }
    Process
    {
        Write-Host "Starting Process"
        Write-Host ""

        $chocoCommand = "choco install $package"
        iex $chocoCommand

        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "Ending Process"
    }

    End
    {
        Write-Host "Now in End"
    }



}

Function Test-Demo
{
    Param ($Param1)
    Begin {
        write-host "Starting"
    }
    Process {
        if($_ -eq " Use --force to reinstall, specify a version to install, or try upgrade.")
        {
         $forceDetected = $true;
        }
        write-host $_
    }
    End {

        if($forceDetected -eq $true)
        {
            Write-Warning "Force detected"
            Write-Warning "Do you want to re-run the installer with --force?"
            # Promt the user Y/N option and re-run testInstall -package $package --force

        }
        write-host "Ending"
    }
}

testInstall -package ruby | Test-Demo Sample
```

This will give me the opportunity to ask the user if he/she wants to re-run the script with the --force parameter. The only problem is that the output from choco has lost its colors. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, I made this. It's in develop, but it parses the output and I can print an installation summary at the end (or whatever I end up doing).

Feel free to comment.

https://github.com/bpjohannessen/ChocoPower

(I will mark this as the answer tomorrow)

Answer (score 1):

Requires Windows Management Framework 5:

```
register-packagesource -Name chocolatey -Provider PSModule -Trusted -Location http://chocolatey.org/api/v2/ -Verbose
```

I found this here: https://serverfault.com/questions/633576/how-do-you-manually-set-powershells-oneget-repository-source-to-chocolatey

You should then be able to run something like this and get verbose output:

```
Get-Package Nodejs | Install-Package -Verbose
```

Comment: This is indeed something I will think about. Thanks for the help!